# How to connect two specific people over the internet for a game on a website

Tags: javascript, html, ip

I have set up a website that mimics a pen-and-paper game called 5x5. Though knowledge of the game is not absolutely necessary, one might find information about this rather amusing game on this website:

http://www222.pair.com/sjohn/blueroom/5x5.htm

The website I made is this one:

http://petercast.net/5x5/

It is very crude and not very eye-pleasing, but the idea is there (in Portuguese). It is meant to be played locally, with two players sat in front of the screen, taking turns using a single set of mouse and keyboard... One types in a word, the other one gives a number back. Then the other one types a word, the first one types a number back. That is basically the dynamics throught the game. It's very simple.

But of course I wonder if I could play against someone over the internet.

I've been looking for ways to make this happen, but everytime I dare google ways to program html games and stuff... It's just not what I want. It's too complex; too much for what I want. I feel like I could do that with HTTP Post method or something, I just don't know how.

I'd like a simple text input field where I could input someone's external IP or something and then the person would do the same with my IP. I really don't know what infrastructure I'd use to make the actual connection happen.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need a server somewhere. Either you run a server that coordinates everything between the two players, or the code starts a server on one of the user's computers. But then you need to enable port forwarding in that user's router, perhaps using UPnP. This is all non-trivial.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, I have two follow-up questions: 1) would you still need to enable port forwarding in that first scenario (a server that coordinates everything between the two players)? 2) what would a server that coordinates stuff sound like... ? I mean, could it be, say, a php page that responds to user input from anywhere like... Like a wordpress comments section?

Comment: 1) No, if you use a central server you don't need port forwarding. Port forwarding is needed to allow a machine behind a router to receive incoming requests, it's not needed if it just makes outgoing requests to a server. 2) It could be something like that.